# Can we influence "Attach to Existing" selection during lead conversion?

Tags: account, leads, lead-conversion

In a standard lead conversion process (no apex, *Require Validation for Converted Leads* activated):
What influences the suggestions `Attach to existing: {accountName}` during lead conversion? And: How can we influence the accounts that are shown?

I assumed adjusting matching and duplicate rules would also affect the suggestions made here, but apparently it does not work that way.
Imagine 30 different "ABC Company" accounts. Currently they are all shown as suggestions but they have a distinct field "CustomerNumber" that is part of the matching and duplicate rule. The goal would be to only display suggestions that are actually found as a potential duplicate, eg. have a similar/the same name **and** a similar "CustomerNumber".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to influence this behavior. If you want to customize the experience at all, you're free to do so, by way of an Action Override. You can use a Visualforce page or Aura Component to override the default behavior and provide a custom interface. You could even query your DuplicateRecord and DuplicateRecordSet entries generated from the Duplicate Rule you created to provide custom matching solutions.